# Django | Почему многие выбирают PostgreSQL?

Tags: python, sql, django, postgresql, sqlite

Почему многие выбирают `PostgreSQL`? На `SQLite3` что ли нельзя захостить сайт? Или он лучше, если да то чем?

Comment: SQLite слишком сильно ориентирована на embedded-решения, что для сайта некомильфо...

Comment: Для небольших сайтов подойдет и SQLite. Насколько я знаю, при больших объемах данных производительность SQLite гораздо хуже. Кроме того, из своего опыта знаю, что у SQLite есть проблемы с регистрозависимыми выборками, приходится писать костыли.

Comment: сталкивался с проблемой, что при написании функций для поиска , все было плохо с русскими буквами, а точнее с их регистром (__icontains не работал)

Comment: https://tproger.ru/translations/sqlite-mysql-postgresql-comparison/